# Imacro Expert? Automation for Messaging Multiple people. HELP wanted.

Tags: firefox, automation, bots, imacros

So I am new to imacro, I tried to record a script that would allow me to message multiple people.

So My plan is open the open profile of multiple people, on different tabs, then message them one by one, Here are the  Steps:

1. Go to tab 1
2. click on message
3. fill the message box with Content
4. click on send
5. close the tab
6. Go to the second Tab and repeat from step 1.....

After recording with I macro, this is the code Iget

```
    TAB T=2
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Message
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:NoFormName TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:message_17336207994662555305 CONTENT=hello
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Send
    TAB CLOSE
```

But the problem here is, I am trying to message mutliple different people, It all works the same Until, filling the message box. On the 5th line of my code you can see that  `ATTR=ID:message_17336207994662555305,` All the user that I am trying to message happen to have different ATTR=ID, because of that I get error, when I run this script with multiple different users.

When I check the site code with firebug, I notice these code

```
<div id="message_15349223200656735391Container" class="inputcontainer textarea empty">
<textarea class="clone" placeholder="Compose your message" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 21px; width: 417px; line-height: 21px; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: 0px;" tabindex="-1"></textarea>
<textarea id="message_15349223200656735391" placeholder="Compose your message" style="height: 42px;"></textarea>
```

So I am wondering is it may be possible to tell the Imacro to target some other class or id that is same on all the profile, instead of "textarea id"
 which is different on every profile.

Kinda trying different stuff, half of the day, since my knowledge is very limited, I would really appreciate a help from you guys.
Thank YOU

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ATTR=ID:message_*
```